# Print CSS not respecting explicit height/overflow: none?

Tags: css, printing, overflow, html

I've written a separate media="print" stylesheet for my page - specifically to resize a div.  In the print CSS, I've given the div an explicit height (in 'pt' units) and a different font-size (also in 'pt').  I've also specified that the div ALWAYS have overflow: hidden (I WANT extra text to get chopped off).

When I print the page, the div doesn't seem to respect the explicit height - it just stretches the div (despite having overflow: hidden);  Since this is a print layout, I'm having a heckuva time troubleshooting it, since I can't use IE Developer tools to trace the CSS/DOM.

BTW, I'm using IE8, with the page in compatibility mode.  I'm in a corporate LAN where all users area GUARANTEED to have either IE7 or IE8, so I actually only need it to work in those;

HTML:

```
<div class="left" style="display: none;">
    <h1 class="corrected">Company Info</h1>
    <div class="box" id="overview_html"></div>
</div>

<div class="right" style="display: none;">
    <h1 class="corrected">Notes</h1>
    <div class="box" id="notes_html"></div>
</div>
```

Print CSS:

```
#notes_html, #overview_html { height: 200pt !important; overflow: hidden; font-size: 12pt; }
```

Screenshots (browser first, then IE's "print preview"):

[image: Browser screenshot]

[image: Print-preview]

Any ideas what's going on?  Are there any "gotchas" to print layout where you can't use overflow: hidden or set an explicit height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***note***: *somewhat blind answer as I can't see your pictures*.

Try using `max-height` instead of `height`. This worked for me.

### edit

The problem is *compatibility mode* : It behave like IE6 : height is treated like min-height (ie "can grow bigger").

Full test case :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        div {
            border: 1px solid red; overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height:50pt
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        div {
            border: 1px solid blue; overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height: 50pt
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
            test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
            test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
        </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, still had the same behavior.  I'm doing some JS stuff on the page, too.  I wonder if that's what's killing it.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ah snap, I forgot about compatibility mode... The issue is that in this mode, `height` is treated as `min-height`. I managed to have it work with a float. __Updated my test case__.